# Browser Automation using GEB and spock can be for an angular js single page applications?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, groovy, spock, geb

I have a Single page application which was developed using AngularJs and Spring MVC framework. So I would like to know is there any way to do Browser Automation using Geb and spock?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried? Do you have a specific issue?

Comment: I am not able to figure out a way to do it. If possible can you share how it can be achieved as in single page application dynamically views will be displayed.

Comment: You'll be better off doing Browser Automation on an AngularJS app using Protractor instead of Geb + Spock: http://angular.github.io/protractor/

Comment: I did this a couple of years ago, but i agree with Alin that protractor seems a better choice. I ran in a lot of timing issues with geb and angular(model not bound yet etc) in the end we got it to work but with a lot of effort, while protractor handles this out of the box.

Comment: @Devnoo can you please share sample snippet which you have worked with geb?